# Отличие разработки под iPhone от разработки под iPad

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Пока нигде не нашел материалов по данной теме, но сразу после установки `xcode` можно заметить, что разработка под iPad предполагает больше возможностей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно больше возможностей:

1. OpenGL ES 2.0 вместо OpenGL ES 1.1 (актуально для айфонов старее 3gs)
2. Размер экрана 768x1024 вместо 320x768.

Comment: только разрешение – 320х480, и 640х960(если Retina)